# Fetch profile image from Azure Active Directory with Next-Auth authentication

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-active-directory, next-auth, azure-authentication

I am able to fetch below details from Azure AD provider while using Next-Auth, but unable to fetch profile picture.

```
{
  ver: '2.0',
  iss: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-0000-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/v2.0',
  sub: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  aud: 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  exp: 0000000000,
  iat: 0000000000,
  nbf: 0000000000,
  name: 'Dibyendu Saha',
  preferred_username: 'dibyendusaha@live.com',
  oid: '00000000-0000-0000-000-0000000000000',
  email: 'dibyendusaha@live.com',
  tid: 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx',
  aio: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}
```

I also want to fetch first name and surname also in addition to profile picture.

I have checked the documentation from 'https://next-auth.js.org/providers/azure-ad'. I have checked the note as well:

> Azure AD returns the profile picture in an ArrayBuffer, instead of
> just a URL to the image, so our provider converts it to a base64
> encoded image string and returns that instead. See:
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#examples.
> The default image size is 48x48 to avoid running out of space in case
> the session is saved as a JWT.

Next Auth Provider code as below:

```
   AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      profile: (profile: AzureADProfile) => {
        console.log(profile);
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
          firstName: profile.name,
          lastName: profile.name
        };
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an Azure AD Application and generated **tokens via *Postman*** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, there is no profile picture details displayed:

[image]

> Note that: To fetch the user's profile picture you need to call Microsoft Graph API. You cannot get user's profile image from Azure AD tokens.

To fetch the User's profile picture, grant **`User.Read.All`** API permission:

[image]

And generate the **access token for Microsoft Graph API** like below:

Pass **scope** as  `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

[image]

Using the above access token, you can **fetch the signed in user's Profile picture** by using below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

[image]

If you want to pass **UserID** make use of below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/photo/$value
```

[image]

To do the same in **`nextauth.js`** use the below sample code:

```js
 providers: [

   AzureADProvider({
     clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
     clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
     tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
     authorization: { params: { scope: "User.Read.All openid offline_access" } },
  }),
 ],
```

```js
async profile(profile, tokens) {
    const profilePicture = await fetch(
    `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photos/${profilePhotoSize}x${profilePhotoSize}/$value`,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokens.access_token}`,
      },
    }
  )

   if (profilePicture.ok) {
    const pictureBuffer = await profilePicture.arrayBuffer()
    const pictureBase64 = Buffer.from(pictureBuffer).toString("base64")
    return {
      id: profile.sub,
      name: profile.name,
      email: profile.email,
      image: `data:image/jpeg;base64, ${pictureBase64}`,
    }
  } else {
    return {
      id: profile.sub,
      name: profile.name,
      email: profile.email,
    }
  }
}
```

**References:**

[Get profilePhoto - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples)

[Azure AD Provider - Profile image doesn't work · Issue #5376 · nextauthjs/next-auth · GitHub](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/5376#issuecomment-1258149479) by drewgillen

Comment: I needed to modify the above solution a lilltle bit.
For authorisation > params > scope, User.Read.All was not working for me though I added the same in Azure AD app permission granted for default directory, so I needed to use User.Read.

Comment: If you are calling /me endpoint then user.read permission must be granted